# javascript display forms from remote url

Tags: javascript

I have dynamic forms in my urls .i want to write a javascript such that when the users paste that javascript in their web pages the form should dispay.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.href = "http://myserver/2a249ccf59e272abb8e7b8582560a45c"
</script>
```

The problem is using the above code , The url redirects.I want to avoid redirection 
I'v tried iframes , but i dont want to use them as per requirements .

Comment: do you mean that you want to escape the html so it is not rendered, and executed, but only displayed visually on the page?

Comment: not exactly..there are dynamic forms in the url's content. if you paste the url in your browser a form would load and display . 
I want to do the same using javascript . Basically i want to fetch the url content using javascript .

Comment: Ok, so this is really a question about AJAX - and how to inject HTML into the page.

Comment: could you give me a solution?

Comment: How are you finding stack overflow so far? If you give yourself a name, and continue to use your account, more people will answer your questions in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use AJAX to fetch a remote page. You must get the page from the same server that your webpage was delivered from to avoid same origin policy issues.

I would recommend using a library to handle AJAX requests. jQuery has AJAX functions built in, but you could use others also. With jQuery...

```
// be sure to include jQuery library in the head of your document...

// general wrapper to execute code only after all page elements have loaded
$(function(){
    $.get("http://myserver/2a249ccf59e272abb8e7b8582560a45c",function(data,status){
        // put the fetched data (your html form) at the end of the existing body content
        // you could put it somewhere else by changing the `body` selector
        $("body").append(data)
    })
})
```